# change imageview in custom tablecell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview, tableview

I have tableview with custom cell. I have textfield and image view in my table cell. When user enters some characters it should validate and change the image view based on user input. My code,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"newsTableCell";
cell = (NewsTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[NewsTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
}
cell.answerTextfield.delegate = self;
if (indexPath.row == 0) {
    cell.newsTitleLabel.text = @"News 1";
    cell.lengthImageView.tag = 300;
}
else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
    cell.newsTitleLabel.text = @"News 2";
    cell.lengthImageView.tag = 301;
}
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    if([NewsValidation charactersInString:string checkFor:@"ValidationString"]) {
        if ([string length] + [textField.text length] > 1 && [textField.text length] < 36) {
            cell.lengthImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Right.png"];
            return YES;
        }
    } else {
        cell.lengthImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Wrong.png"];
        return NO;
    }
   return YES;
}
```

NewsTableViewCell.h

```
@interface NewsTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {
      IBOutlet UIImageView *lengthImageView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)IBOutlet UIImageView *lengthImageView;
```

When am entering values in textfield, condition goes finely but image view not getting updated based on input. Am getting object value for cell.Did I miss something? Kindly help me to sort out this issue. TIA.

Comment: I'd suggest you to make your tableview cell as delegate of your textField and implement delegate methods to your custom tableviewcell class. Then change image as wanted.

Comment: do you want to change image view of all the `UITableViewCell` cells ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get the Cell for desired row

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
         NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:4 inSection:0]; 
         NewsTableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if([NewsValidation charactersInString:string checkFor:@"ValidationString"]) {
        if ([string length] + [textField.text length] > 1 && [textField.text length] < 36) {
            cell.lengthImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Right.png"];
            return YES;
        }
    } else {
        cell.lengthImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Wrong.png"];
        return NO;
    }
   return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try reloading table view cells when you enter text in text field.